# P-values seem to be zero in an nlsfit model

Tags: r, p-value

I am running a gompertz equation with nlsfit in R. Everything seems to go well, but I don't get the p-values when running the following model.

```
modelP1 <- nlsfit(dataP1GS, model = 10, start = c(a = 30, b = 1.5, c = 0.053))
```

I got this:

```
[1] "y~a*exp(-b*exp(-c*x)"

$Parameters
                             GP
coefficient a         28.954458
coefficient b          2.318146
coefficient c          0.136665
p-value t.test for a   0.000000
p-value t.test for b   0.000000
p-value t.test for c   0.000000
r-squared              0.986800
adjusted r-squared     0.986400
AIC                  182.721758
BIC                  191.099137.
```

It is really hard to browse for information when there is no red line or error!

Update: I am still struggling! I will post part of my data set, I hope someone can give me a hint!

```
    Hour    GP
1   2   7.9
2   4   9.9
3   6   11.2
4   8   13.3
5   12  17.4
6   16  21
7   24  27
8   36  32.8
9   48  36.8
10  60  38.4
11  72  40
12  96  41
13  2   7.1
14  4   8.7
15  6   9.1
16  8   11.7
17  12  14.8
18  16  18.7
19  24  25
20  36  30.9
21  48  35.4
22  60  36.8
23  72  39
24  96  40
25  2   8.1
26  4   10.4
27  6   11.5
28  8   14.2
29  12  15.6
30  16  19.1
31  24  25.6
32  36  29.6
33  48  33.8
34  60  35.2
35  72  36.6
36  96  37.6
37  2   7.9
38  4   12
39  6   15
40  8   17.3
41  12  20.8
42  16  23.3
43  24  27.8
44  36  31.4
45  48  33.8
46  60  35.4
47  72  36.3
48  96  37.6
49  2   7.3
50  4   10.8
51  6   12.4
52  8   16.5
53  12  19.3
54  16  22.5
55  24  26.4
56  36  29.4
57  48  32.4
58  60  34.8
59  72  35.8
60  96  38.2
```

Comment: Is this related to r? Please add the relevant tag for the language

Comment: You are right I forgot it, yes it is related to R., Thank you